# how to reload main activity after click "OK" on AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

I have an AlertDialog and I want the Main Activity to reload after I have click "OK". The problem is after I have click OK my activity returned to the home screen.

**JAVA Code :**

```
private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(
        "This application needs GPS satellite or Wireless Networks localization enabled" 
        + "\n" + "Do you want to enable it?")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(
            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }

    })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
            dialog.cancel();


        }
    });

    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    alert.show();

}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to remove finish() call.

Answer (score 2):

Change this code

```
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
        startActivity(new Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }
```

to

```
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call onCreate method again. But pass null as a parameter.

```
onCreate(null);
```